# Author/Id returning number instead of name

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using the following URL to get data from a list. The last item in the URL is the Author/Id but it returns a number.

How can I get the user's name instead of the number?

```
url: https://.../org/eu/EU3/EU34/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EU34SupportTracker')/items?$select=Title,Attachments,AttachmentFiles,Worklog&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id
```

Comment: You can write multiple fields in single `$expand` and `$select`. No need to write it multiple times. try my answer given below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$select=Author/Name,Author/Title&$expand=Author
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Amos. I used Author/Title and I got the name I was trying to get.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is correct. In order to get the name of user you need to use below REST API URL:

```
https://.../org/eu/EU3/EU34/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EU34SupportTracker')/items?$select=Title,AttachmentFiles,Worklog,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName&$expand=AttachmentFiles,Author
```

Or If you have set the display name to user fields then you can also use:

```
Author/Title
```

instead of `Author/FirstName` and `Author/LastName`